# php sql Variable

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to load $location into the sql query but just returning Invalid:

```
//query to Equipment

$Location= $_GET["id"];

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `Equipment` WHERE `Location` = `".$Location."`"); 

$result = $sql;
if (!$result) 
{
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());

}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
```

The `$_GET['id']` is called from another page. I double checked link says id

Comment: 1. Use *quotes*, not backticks, around values (backticks are for table/column names). 2. Use *prepared queries*, right now you're wide open to injection.

Comment: another suggestion; use PDO, the API is **much** easier

Comment: use:
$Location= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);

Comment: ' ".$location" ' not ``

Comment: the href should look like in the end home.php?id=24

Comment: @Ruben That advice is, frankly, completely wrong. First, the `mysql_*` API is deprecated in 5.* and removed entirely in 7.0. Second, escaping is *not* the way to go. Prepared statements are necessary to prevent injection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Dave Baker try something like below :

```
<?php
    $Location = isset($_GET["id"]) ? $_GET["id"] : 0;
    if($Location){
        $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Equipment WHERE Location = $Location"); //if location type is integer else use below one
        $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Equipment WHERE Location = '$Location'"); //if location type is string

        $result = $sql;
        if (!$result) 
        {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());

        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {}

    }
    else{
        echo "id is not set";
    }
```